# C++ and ode system: how to handle it?

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen, numeric

I want to code a class to solve **systems** of ODEs with Euler method in C++ (I'm a beginner). If the equation is scalar, there's no problem, since I can store the solution in a `vector` or I can dinamiccaly allocate an array with `double* sol = new double[N_points]`

Things starts to get weird to me if I have to handle matrices, so my question is: **should I use some library as `Eigen`? Or should I struggle with pointers?

I'm looking for some good way/reference to be sure which is the correct/best method to handle such a situation.

Comment: The answer is rarely "struggle with pointers". Get a library or you'll be forced to write and debug one yourself. In C++ use `std::vector` whenever you can vs. `new[]`.

Comment: @tadman thanks for your suggestion. But vector is just for the scalar case, while here I should store the solution in an matrix

Comment: @tadman also, why should I avoid dynamic allocation?

Comment: If you dynamically allocate you *must* free that memory eventually, which can be hard to keep track of. `std::vector` and other containers will handle that for you. Memory management in C++ can get dizzyingly complicated if the ownership of each allocation isn't clear, and there's a very fine line between easily understood and completely confusing.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for pointing that out. The problem with vectors is that it's not "easy" to access elements if I want to use them to handle "matrices"

Comment: @Vefhug Why? All it takes is a one liner. Here: `struct Matrix { int rows=0, cols=0; std::vector<double> data; double &operator()(int row, int col) { return data[row*cols + col]; } void resize(int rows, int cols) { this->rows=rows; this->cols=cols; data.resize(rows*cols); } };` Note that both `row` and `col` must be 0-based. This performs better than the array-of-pointers approach, too. `foo[row][col]` is ugly vs. `foo(row,col)`. If you prefer Fortran-style indexing (1-based), you'd use `double &operator()(int row, int col) { return data[(row-1)*cols + col - 1]; }`.

Comment: It's actually really easy so long as you shift your expectations. The answer by Vinicius is a good example of how. Remember many libraries like [vectormath](https://github.com/glampert/vectormath) provide proper matrix constructors if you prefer that.

Comment: @all thanks for your comments, really useful. I'm a beginner and still don't know anything about struct, so I'm going to study them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with matrices you can do this with array of arrays, or use a simplified abstraction layer with an one dimensional array (or vector) to store the matrix data, like:

```cpp
std::vector<double> matrix(row * columns);
```

To access an item, you can use simple arithmetic, like:

```
int index = rowIndex * totalColumns + columnIndex;
double item = matrix[index];
```

You can have a look at my **[DoubleMatrix](https://github.com/viniciusalmada/Double-Matrix-Lib/blob/master/DoubleMatrixLibrary/src/DoubleMatrix.cpp)** library (not use it, just check out) to have an examples of this implementation.

Comment: I think that this way to access an item is a bit error-prone in the context of numerical analysis. Do you know by chanche any other method?

Comment: You can be more exact and use a container of container like `std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix`. When you access, can use `matrix[row][col]`

Comment: *I think that this way to access an item is a bit error-prone* Nobody here actually means that you'd repeat this access pattern everywhere. You should code it once, and use that code everywhere you perform access. In C you'd have an access function, in C++ you'd have methods.

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada just one more question: if I want to do something like ```matrix[:,0] ``` (all rows, first column), do I have to do a loop everytime?

Comment: @Vefhug well, yeah. If you are coming from MATLAB, don't think that is what it doesn't do under the hood. You can make other access method that returns to you a subvector of the matrix, like `matrix.subvector(ALL_ROWS, 3)` passing a flag to every rows or every columns. Only depending of your needs